# Bash: How to get size of image compressed with JPEG2000

Tags: imagemagick

I encoded image with jPEG2000 standard, how to get size of image after compression.

```
identify inputimage.pgm
```

works but

```
identify inputimage.jpc
```

does not work.
error is "identify: no decode delegate for this image format `J2K' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/501."

Comment: It seems it is related to the way ImageMagick was installed / compiled. Can you specify your environment?

Comment: My environment is Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test which image formats your **ImageMagick** installation is able to read/write by running:

```
identify -list format
```

And further, which files **ImageMagick** is able to read/write by *"delegating"* out to a *"helper program"*, by running:

```
identify -list delegate
```

If you are on Linux and missing JPEG2000, you will probably need to have installed the following before running `./configure` to configure **ImageMagick**:

- pkg-config
- libopenjpeg
- libopenjp2-7-dev

---

On a Mac under macOS at least, that means you need to have done:

```
brew install openjpeg
brew install imagemagick --with-openjpeg      # Use "reinstall" if already installed
```

Comment: Hi, I did as you suggested, but it seems that JPEG2000 is still missing. Please recommend something else. Thank You.

Comment: You may need to install `pkgconf` (maybe `pkg-config`) before installing ImageMagick in order for ImageMagick to find `OpenJPEG`.

Comment: I just found you need to install `libopenjp2-7-dev` with `sudo apt-get install libopenjp2-7-dev` before you run `./configure` and install ImageMagick.

Comment: Older versions of ImageMagick used the Jasper delegate library for JP2000. Newer versions starting at about IM 6.8.9-1 use OpenJPEG 2.1 or higher.

Answer (score 1):

Error messages says `identify` did not find necessary library to handle JPEG2000. You can check output of `identify -list format` to confirm that.

Indeed, it seems that [JPEG2000 support is not enable in last versions of Ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/imagemagick/+bug/1447968). [Debian fixed this issue a while ago](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=773530). So I suggest:

- Install another distribution (Debian for exemple)
- Rebuild imagemagick package with support for JPEG2000

Under Ubuntu, you can rebuild ImageMagick with JPEG2000 support following these steps:

```
apt-get source imagemagick
sudo apt-get build-dep imagemagick
sudo apt-get install libopenjp2-7-dev
dpkg-buildpackage -uc -us
sudo dpkg -i *deb
```

Answer (score 0):

If ImageMagick does not the trick, you can try using exiftool:

```
exiftool -FileSize inputimage.jpc
```

Comment: I tried this, but the result is not accurate. the size of image is less as compared to size shown in properties of image.